# When does Python evaluate a variable in a function definition

Tags: python, variables, scope

I am confused as when does Python evaluates a variable. For example if I do:

```
p=4
def g():
    return p
p=5
print g()
```

I get 5, so in the definition of `g`, the variable `p` remains unevaluated. It is evaluated when we call `g`

However if I do:

```
def make_fun():
    p=5
    def f():
        return p
    return f

f=make_fun()
p=6
print f()
```

I get 5. Why does not`f` contains the unevaluated variable `p`? I would like to have a clear idea as of when precisely the evaluation of variables takes place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python executes the code as it loads the module / script. Hence in your first example it's not "evaluated when we call g", it simply means that the latest value of `p` is 5 at the time when `g` is executed. Python will lookup `p` and it'll return the current value (5).

In your second example `p` is a local variable. That means it's not affected by `p = 6` in the global scope. Or to be clear, the `p` in `f()` in your second example is the local variable set within `make_fun()`. So that's the value you'll get back, it's not the `p` at the outer (global) scope, which is a different `p`.

Answer (score 3):

```
p=4          #you are setting global p to 4
def g():
    return p
p=5          #you are setting global p to 5
print g()    #you are printing the result of g, which is not setting any value;
```

so 5 is printed;
but here:

```
def make_fun():
    p=5          #you are setting local p to 5
    def f():
        return p
    return f

f=make_fun()
p=6              #you are setting global p to 6
print f()        #you printing the result of a function in f, which is getting the local p
```

so local p= 5 is printed;

hope i understood you right!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a question of when evaluation takes place.  In both of your examples, `p` is evaluated when the function is called.  The real question is when does that variable get declared.

In your first example, `p` is declared outside of the function and therefore has global scope.  Any changes to `p` impact it wherever it it referenced.

In your second example, you are declaring another variable `p` inside the function.  This is local to the function and not impacted by any code outside of the function.  Even if you then go ahead and declare another global `p` as you do in the line after `f=make_fun()`, this global variable is overridden within the function by the local variable.

As an experiment, try printing `p` after you print `f()` and you'll see that it's value will be 6 as you assigned it.